# formview not showing in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

Here is my aspx code. im using a formview and fixed values in which i used an asp.label. but when i run it, formview doesnt show up. i dont have any code behind in which i think i lack? i really appreciate any help. thanks in advance!

```
<asp:FormView ID="EmployeeFormView" HorizontalAlign="Center"

            DataKeyNames="ID"    
            Gridlines="Both" 

            RunAt="server"
    BackColor="#FFFF66"
    BorderColor="#FF8080">

            <HeaderStyle backcolor="Navy"
              forecolor="#999966"/>

            <RowStyle backcolor="White" ForeColor="#CC3300"/>        

            <EditRowStyle backcolor="#FFFFFF" ForeColor="#FF9966"/>

            <ItemTemplate>
              <table id="tblcustomerprofile" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
                   <tr>
                        <td style="width:100px">
                            ID:
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:250px">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="10999574"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                   <tr>
                        <td style="width:100px">
                            Name:
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:250px">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Paolo Duhaylungsod"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            Age:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="24"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            Birth Date:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="06/29/1990"></asp:Label>
                        </td>                                                                                  
                    </tr>
                        <tr>                            
                        <td>
                            Citizenship:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Filipino"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <tr>                            
                        <td>
                            Status:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="Single"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="width:100px">
                            Email Address:
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:250px">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="paolodexter@yahoo.com"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="width:100px">
                            College:
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:250px">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="De La Salle- College of Saint Benilde"></asp:Label>
                        </td>                            
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Course:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="BS- Information Systems"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            Contact Number:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="09255666167"></asp:Label>
                        </td>                                                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Address:
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Bf Resort Village, Las Pinas"></asp:Label>
                        </td>                                                        
                    </tr>                         
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add the default mode property to your formview.

```
defaultmode="Edit"
```

without this the formview would be set to show the empty data template.

You could also try to just add all of your code to the empty data template of the formview then it should all show up

Comment: tried putting in all inside <emptydatatemplate> and added deaultmode, still not showing

Comment: Are you actually trying to bind data from a database into the formview? I'm wondering If Formview control needs a datasource to work properly

Comment: If you don't actually need to pull data you are probably better off just setting up a Panel control and putting your labels on the Panel